# QtGui4.dll entry point not found

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt4, qt4.8

I'm trying to write Qt3D application in windows. I'm getting an error when i trying to compile the program and run it. the error's message is : 'The procedure entry point ??4QImage@@AEAAV0@$$QAV0@@Z could not be found in the dynamic link library QtGui4.dll'.
my compiler is Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 and Qt version is 4.8.1.
is there any solution for this?

Comment: Do you get the error when you compile or when you run? I suspect the latter. Ensure that there are no other copies of Qt library in your PATH. Sometimes happens that there are older versions shipped with programs that are in PATH (MiKTeX, LyX, TortoiseHG for example). Try executing your program from a command line prompt, after having set the PATH: `set PATH=C:\path\to\qt;%PATH%`. If that works set the PATH system widely.

Answer (score 2):

Do you face the problem in both running from the IDE and standalone exe, and both in debug and release mode. IF some of these work, make sure proper QtGui4.dll is copied to the same path where your executable is getting generated.